# I can’t see ads on any SE sites I am active on. A bug?

Tags: support, advertising

I’m expecting to see some of the much Meta-discussed ads on all the sites  where I am active, but nothing yet, at least nothing on my devices (I use mainly a tablet and a phone).

Is it a question of priority with most active sites top of the list and slow traffic sites down the line, a question of devices, a bug or else?

Comment: Haven't checked how the two combine, but there's a "see less ads privilege" at ~200 rep. I don't see any ads on SFF when logged in (on phone at least)

Comment: Lol, AdBlock and NoScript means the answer is a resounding, "No".  Combine that with pi-hole.net for adblocking on your tablet and phone apps.

Comment: @MaxVernon - ads are visible from the same devices on other socials like Facebook and others.

Comment: How to get this bug ? asking for myself.

Comment: uBlock nukes ads on multiple sites, including YouTube and Facebook from my experience.

Comment: Nothing official, but on mobile, from experience I don't see ads on beta sites, sites I have more than 200 rep on, and few of the "technical" sites. From memory I saw ads on TWP, Travel, SFF, Movies, ELU, Biology, Chemistry, SO (but different ad server I believe), Music, Arqade, Anime, Academia, RPG, Worldbuilding.

Comment: Try viewing in anonymous mode?

Comment: I don't remember ever seeing an ad on SE, but the only sites I frequented were ELU, TGO, SFF,  and PFM.  But then my reptilian brain automatically turns off the circuit to  my cerebral cortex whenever an ad appears.  (Past tense, because I may not continue with SE because of this abhorrent mess.)

Comment: Just a guess, did you list your birthday as being under age? I've seen posts about inappropriate ads

Comment: You should take to Twitter and vehemently declaim that you feel unwelcomed because you aren't getting the same ads as everyone else. SE Inc. will be so terrified at the potential loss of ad revenue, that they'll probably make an announcement on Meta about fixing it right away (whether they'll follow through or not is anyone's guess); and maybe even give you some moderator diamonds to make up for it -- there are quite a few open moderator positions now. (Sorry, I couldn't resist :) )

Comment: @ZevSpitz - I’m pleased to give you an opportunity  to give vent to your feelings about this mess.